# How to configure value object for Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create migration but don't not how to configure an Entity Framework to work with property with custom type.

My ValueObject `BrandName` class:

```
public class BrandName : ValueObject<BrandName>
{
    public string Value { get; }

    private BrandName(string name)
    {
        Value = name;
    }

    public static Result<BrandName> Create(string brandName) 
    {
        brandName = (brandName ?? string.Empty).Trim();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(brandName)) 
        {
            return Result.Fail<BrandName>(BrandValidationValues.BrandNameEmpty);
        }

        if (brandName.Length > BrandValidationValues.BrandNameLength) 
        {
            return Result.Fail<BrandName>(BrandValidationValues.BrandNameTooLong);
        }

        return Result.Ok(new BrandName(brandName));
    }

    protected override bool EqualsCore(BrandName other)
    {
        return Value.Equals(other.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    protected override int GetHashCodeCore()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static implicit operator string(BrandName brandName)
    {
        return brandName.Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator BrandName(string brandName)
    {
        return Create(brandName).Value;
    }
}
```

My Entity Brand class:

```
public class CatalogBrand : Entity
{
    private string _name;

    public virtual BrandName Name
    {
        get => (BrandName)_name;
        set => _name = value;
    }
}
```

Configuration for Entity Framework:

```
class BrandEntityTypeConfiguration
: IEntityTypeConfiguration<CatalogBrand>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CatalogBrand> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Brand");

        builder.HasKey(ci => ci.Id);

        builder.Property(ci => ci.Id)
            .UseHiLo("brand_hilo")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(cb => cb.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```

Error which I get:

> The property 'CatalogBrand.Name' is of type 'BrandName' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: He does not know how to handle the ValueObject.

Add a custom conversion (.HasConversion(ValueObjectConverter) to the Property in the EntityConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's going to help but going to say:
If you are getting this error, you are not defining that this is my value object and I don't need to create a table for it, it's just a field of my table, so you need to tell the EF in the model configuration in this way:
`builder.HasOne(x => x.Name);`
You can use `OwnOne` and `OwnMany` for configuration.